# Not able to get List from inside bean in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to create print a list of strings on my jsp with the information in a bean called copa, stored in the session.

```
<jsp:useBean id="copa" class="Beans.CopaBean" scope="session"/>

                                <c:forEach var="item" items="${copa.mSelecciones}">
                                       ${item.mNombre}
                                    </c:forEach>
```

My object copa, implements `java.io.Serializable`. Inside it has a List of objects that do also implement this interface.
I can also see the copa object being filled in the variables tab in NetBeans and the collection of mSelecciones with data inside..

I have tryied absolutely everything..from making the property mSelecciones public, to change the name to be shorter, to invoke the get method, getmSelecciones() ,etc but I have not been able to get my code to print any text on the html.

Any help?

This is the printout in the HTML when I run the code, as you can see I have the two objects sitting there..just cant iterate them.

```
 <c:forEach var="a" items="[Beans.SeleccionBean@7022efdf, Beans.SeleccionBean@5b252fd]">

                                    </c:forEach>
```

This is my CopaBean class structure :

```
    public class CopaBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    public  List<SeleccionBean> mSelecciones = null;


    public List<SeleccionBean> getmSelecciones() throws SQLException {
     }
}
```

This is my SeleccionesBean class structure :

```
    public class SeleccionBean  implements java.io.Serializable{
    private String mNombre;
    public String getmNombre() {
            return mNombre;
     }
}
```

Comment: It must follow the class structure completely. For ex: If you have your list B inside class A, then use class="A" and inside just do <c:forEach var="x" items="${B}"...

Comment: I did not quite get your comment, I believe I am doing what yoou said.. or yoou mean instead of var="item" I should put something like var="Beans.Selecciones"?

Comment: No, there is no problem with var. Can you edit the post so that I can get an idea of the class structure? Try ${mSelecciones} rather than ${copa.mSelecciones}

Comment: editted, I tried doing mSelecciones but did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried `item.getmNombre()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **JSTL**, thus you must use *JavaBean naming conventions* for all methods you intend to use with **JSTL**.

For example, the statement `<c:forEach var="item" items="${copa.mSelecciones}`, fails because the java application server is attempting to resolve the method `CopaBean.getMSelecciones()` and cannot find it. Note that the `M` is capitalized. Also, note that the `m` in your method is not!

For the app server to resolve the method, you must ensure its name follows *JavaBean naming conventions*. e.g. getters and setters must be in the form `getSomeMethod`, `setSomeMethod`, respectively. Notice that the first letter following the get/set is capitalized.

To fix you code, change

```
public List<SeleccionBean> getmSelecciones() throws SQLException {
```

to

```
public List<SeleccionBean> getMSelecciones() throws SQLException {
```

You also have the same problem with `SeleccionBean.getmNombre()`. Change it to `SeleccionBean.getMNombre()`.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaBean convention is to define getters and setters by using "set" or "get" followed by the name of the property with the first letter upper cased, i.e. for `mSelecciones`, the getter would be `getMSelecciones()`, not `getmSelecciones()`. Same with `mNombre` -> `getMNombre()`

Comment: Did not work, and luckily the parser is not so lazy and does not look for the first upper-case letter to be the delimiter..